# Logstash Input File - Read From Desktop File

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am having issues reading logs from a source file on my desktop.  My current Logstash config file is:

```
input 
{
  file 
  {
    path => ["C:/users/Me/Desktop/Dum.txt"]
  }
}

output 
{
  stdout { }
  elasticsearch { host => localhost }
}
```

I am streaming the output to Kibana, which is working properly using a stdin {} configuration.

The dummy source file (Dum.txt) is:

```
2014-05-20T17:42:49.694+0000 MyCompID Agent
```

The config file runs, and there is seemingly no issue with it being stable.

I also tried using a CSV file for input with the same luck.

Thank you for your help with this!

Comment: I was able to solve the issue.  The stream was open, but I had to save the file with NEW data for it to read to the ELK.

AutoSave needs to be set to ensure that the file is updated and the output is generated.

Comment: Sorry what was the solution ?

Comment: As long as the text file changes in some way, such as adding a line or removing a line of data, the Logstash agent/shipper will pick up the change and send it off to your Elasticsearch instance.

Essentially, the file needed to be written over or appended to.  To view this, manually select all from the file, cut the text, save the file, paste the text back into the file, and save it once again.  You will see the stream posting to the prompt if you are using stdout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Copied from the Comments of the Question)

I was able to solve the issue. The stream was open, but I had to save the file with NEW data for it to read to the ELK. AutoSave needs to be set to ensure that the file is updated and the output is generated.

As long as the text file changes in some way, such as adding a line or removing a line of data, the Logstash agent/shipper will pick up the change and send it off to your Elasticsearch instance. Essentially, the file needed to be written over or appended to. To view this, manually select all from the file, cut the text, save the file, paste the text back into the file, and save it once again. You will see the stream posting to the prompt if you are using stdout